# I need a CSS editor that will help me see what is applied

Tags: css

I am somewhat frustrated as I have yet to find a CSS editor that I can point at an HTML web page and see the style applied.  What would be nice is to be able to do the following -
open a web page and view it as if it were in a browser. As you mouse over different regions see in another region of the tool what style is being applied from where, i.e. a style sheet or the default browser.  The ability to interactively edit the style in the style sheet and save it to the style sheet.  Intellisense help with the editing of the style sheet.

Is there any such style sheet editing tool out there like that.  I don't care if it is free or a paid for product I just want this capability.

Comment: go to any web page and open developer tools in chrome/IE/firefox

Comment: What you are looking for is called firebug

Answer (score 1):

You don't particularly need an editor to quickly see how and where styles are being applied to elements.  You can use web developer tools built into most modern browsers.

In any browser, hit your F12 key and you'll be presented with a developer panel.

Look for something called the "Inspector tool".  It's usually represented by a mouse or search glass icon.  Clicking this will allow you to select any element on the page and view the CSS applied to it.

Alternatively, you can just right click any element on a page and click "Inspect Element".  This will bring up the developer tools with the element selected.

With the Line number and style information present, you can fiddle with the results directly in the developer tools window, then go over to a CSS editor of your choice and apply the changes.

Comment: most of those developer tools on the browsers allow you to copy the code as well, then you just have to paste it in the right place

Answer (score 1):

I use the FireFox browser with the FireBug addon installed.  You can see the exact cascade being applied to each HTML element, and edit it directly in FireBug and see the results instantly.

Comment: this covers Firefox, but what about Chrome, Safari, Opera, Internet Explorer, and the other weird ones that a handful of people use? CSS is different across the different browsers

Answer (score 0):

every browser interprets CSS Style differently,  especially if we are talking about Internet Explorer.  so it would not do you much good to use a tool like this anyway.  you would be better off testing the code in different browsers, or at least the browsers that matter most to your audience.  and utilizing their Developer tools. FireBug on FireFox, Chrome's Built in Code inspecter, IE's Developer Tools